# How Do I get my Number Diamond to have zeros and and altered rows?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, logic, ascii

So I have a functional set of code that prints a diamond of numbers based on user input, but I'm looking to make the diamond into a square, with empty spaces being filled with zeros. I also want to alter how the rows look. How do I alter my logic to make this look like my included example?

```
//Code for top half

var ast = [],
    i, j = rows;

for (i = 0; i <= j; i+=2) {
  ast[i] = new Array(i + 2).join([i+1]);
  //  console.log(ast[i]);
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML+=ast[i] + '<br />';
}

//<!-- Code for bottom half - -->

var ast = [],
    i, j = rows-1;

for (i = j-2; i >=0; i-=2) {
  ast[i] = new Array(i + 2).join([i+1]);
  //   console.log(ast[i]);
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML+=ast[i] + '<br />';
}
```

I'd like my diamond to look like this:

```
00100
03130
53135
03130
00100
```

Instead of how it looks now:

```
  1
 333
55555
 333
  1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOVerflow!  Please visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you written that code? If so, why did you pass an array to `.join` instead of the number itself?

Comment: I did not write this code, but I found that it worked this way when I was playing around with it. I'm new at coding, so is there a better way? I find that it throws the wrong values when I change it from an array to the number. Is there a reason not to do it this way?